# install libopencv-dev without libopencv-ocl-dev

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-13.10

I recently update my os to Ubuntu 13.10 64bit, when I ran

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

My computer crashes.

The reason is that

```
libopencv-dev -> libopencv-ocl-dev -> nvida-319
```

using

```
aptitude why libopencv-dev nvidia-319
p   libopencv-dev     Depends  libopencv-ocl-dev (= 2.4.5+dfsg-0ubuntu4)
p   libopencv-ocl-dev Depends  libopencv-ocl2.4 (= 2.4.5+dfsg-0ubuntu4) 
p   libopencv-ocl2.4  Depends  libopencl1                               
p   nvidia-319        Provides libopencl1
```

And it is the nvida-319 crashes my computer

So how can install libopencv-dev without libopencv-ocl-dev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-libopencl1
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

`nvidia` is just one provider of libopencl1. There is also the ATI version for example. It is called `ati-opencl1`. The ATI OpenCL implementation will even work -- on the CPU. Install that first and aptitude will not try to install the `nvidia` package.

Depending on your Ubuntu version it may be that you have to install the `fglrx-driver` package instead (`ati-opencl1` is a part of it).

Comment: my computer is ThinkPad T420, which is intel graphics.

Comment: It does not matter, you can still install the ATI opencl package and use it. As I said it will work on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any intel graphics drivers for opencv on ubuntu 13.10 x64? (or another version)
I also found this link also but without answer :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/365897/how-to-install-opencv-without-nvidia-drivers

Comment: currently i am using sudo apt-get install libopencv-highgui-dev, and then compile from source, which is great.